# Between two rectangles, find closest possible position such that edges of rectangles touch

Tags: geometry

I've got two rectangles, both with a known size and rotation. First rectangle (red) rotates around a pivot point at a known position within itself. When the edge of first rectangle touches the second rectangle (blue) it must push/pull it so that it moves along a predefined line (green).

How can I calculate the center position of the second rectangle?

[image: Example of setup]

My initial thought was to move the rect2 along the green line out of reach (Distance would be: rect1 pivot point to its furthest away corner + distance from center of rect2 to one of its corners). Then calculate then nearest position on rect1. But I'm lost from here, incl. finding the nearest position on rect1.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen I've updated the question